# PHP RegExpr error Unkown modifier '('

Tags: php, regex

I have this regular expression:

```
([http://some.url.com/index.php?showtopic=\"]*)([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?)
```

its for extracting links to topics from forum

Now when i use it in my script

```
$url = "([http://some.url.com/index.php?showtopic=\"]*)([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?)";
```

preg_match_all spits: "Unknown modifier '('"

This is also the call to preg_match

```
preg_match_all($url, $str, $matches,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE,3);
```

Can anyone help me with this obviously stupid problem

Comment: That's an odd regular expression. It'll match "nice.rum.is.nice.1234" just as easily as it'll match that URL. Are you sure you want to be using a character class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PCRE](http://php.net/pcre) requires [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) that separate the actual regular expression from [optional modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). With PHP you can use any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character and even delimiters that come in pairs (brackets).

In your case the leading `(` is used as delimiter and the first corresponding closing `)` marks the end of the regular expression; the rest is treated as modifiers:

```
([http://some.url.com/index.php?showtopic=\"]*)([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?)
^                                             ^
```

But the first character after the ending delimiter (`(`) is not a valid modifier. That why the error message says *Unknown modifier '`(`'*.

In most cases `/` is used as delimiter like in Perl. But that would require to escape each occurrence of `/` in the regular expression. So it’s a good choice to choose a delimiter that’s not in the regular expression. In your case you could use `#` like BoltClock suggested.

Oh, and by the way: A character class like `[http://some.url.com/index.php?showtopic=\"]` represents just one single character of the listed characters. So either `h`, `t`, `p`, `:`, `/`, etc. If you mean to express `http://some.url.com/index.php?showtopic="` literally, use just `http://some\.url\.com/index\.php\?showtopic="` (don’t forget to escape the meta characters).

Comment: thanks guys but after i realized my expression is not correct, so i spend some time changing it.

Answer (score 6):

You need to wrap your regular expression in delimiters. Any character that isn't a special PCRE metacharacter will do, so I'll use `#`:

```
$url = "#([http://some.url.com/index.php?showtopic=\"]*)([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?)#";
```

You can learn more about delimiters in [the PHP manual section for PCRE delimiters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

Comment: thanks guys but both of the examples shows an error:

 unexpected '}', expecting '('

Which is in my string to match, so what is wrong with this one, why is taking content of the string into account?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the code containing the preg_match_all() call and the delimited regex?