# Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, preg-replace

I have the following error:

> Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier ']' in xxx.php on line 38

This is the code on line 38:

```
<?php echo str_replace("</ul></div>", "", preg_replace("<div[^>]*><ul[^>]*>", "", wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'nav', 'echo' => false)) )); ?>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Add delimeters around the pattern: `"/<div[^>]*><ul[^>]*>/"`

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation about `preg_replace()`?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: @mario I don't really see why you put a bounty here? Are you really looking for new answers here? If yes what's wrong with the current one?

Comment: @Rizier123  The bounty description says it all: *"One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty."*

Comment: Yes, this isn't meant to attract more answers. The existing one is a pretty excellent example already. It's a great visual explaination, and likely applicable to many similar cases. And such mini bounties are mainly intended as *temporary **public bookmark*** - to make it better known. And perhaps establish this as another universal reference. (Though could make sense to craft an artificial CW answer with extra examples + links afterwards…)

Comment: @mario If this should get an *artifical* answer, shouldn't we change the example a bit? I mean the OP is parsing HTML with regexes. I'm with you that the answer shows a lot of effort (and I like him and his posts) but I'm asking: Is this necessary? I mean a short "You need to enclose your regex with a delimiter" and a link to the (very good!) [documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) would have been enough. Isn't it? IMHO all that extra information is going into the wrong direction and may confuse (expected newbie) users more than it helps.

Comment: @hek2mgl Good point. I didn't really take the HTMLishness into account. While this makes it somewhat of a special case (amounts to accidentially using one of the possible delimiter `<` `>` pairs), it still seems generic and trivial enough. The existing answer should probably cover just that mainly. But a second more generialized / CW answer of course can just *introduce new examples*. (Perfectly fine IMO.) -- Also of course, a RTM / manual link + closing would indeed be sufficient for most of these questions. But I figured this one could make a more convenient dupeclosing alternative.

Comment: @mario Go with whatever you like, I don't have any issues with that. But let me add that one of the advantages of PHP compared to other scripting languages (like Ruby, Python, Perl) is it's very good documentation. I'm working more with other languages atm and believe me, I often wish to have a PHP-like documentation. We should point this out as often as possible (IMHO ;) ) - and help to improve it when needed.

Comment: @hek2mgl I feel you. In particular Ruby and Python docs are somewhat of a hit and miss at times. Very glad for the `pman` version of the PHP docs, btw ;)  -- Also I'm just gonna wait out where this is going, perhaps cut down the example answer, and/or make a second/broader one.

Comment: @mario I suggest to change the string in the example to something like `[2015/07/02 00:00:00]`. It shows the same characteristics as the current one but we would not have to deal with the HTML-Regex issue.

Comment: @hek2mgl Yes something like that, or perhaps a BBCode/Smarty example `{bold[^}]+}` to retain the `[^DELIM]` gotcha. It's probably okay even if the question itself lists a few different / believably common examples. (Admittedly haven't really looked around much; but I guess it could summarize some of the more recurring issues.)

Comment: @mario ^^ Seems like we got some other things cleared here :) (I original asked, because I was confused of the bounty message: *One or more of the answers...*, because I think you can't do it much better than the existing one, so I was confused)

Comment: @mario I think you have to award the bounty manually, since the answer wasn't posted in the bounty period. Otherwise I think the bounty will just go nowhere. (Also why did you deleted your answer? It doesn't looks bad)

Comment: @Rizier123 I'll tick it off in 7.5 hours. Bounties awards are valid up to 24h afterwards. In my experience you get most views at the very end of bounty periods anyway. Probably won't attract new answers (unneeded; but didn't want to dissuade anyone still). Which is also why I've kept the CW answer in "sneak mode". Gonna finish it up with explaining the delimiter extraction in `pcre.c`, then undelete it again. Votes in the meantime really belong to the main answer. The CW is just addendum really :]

Comment: @mario Ah yeah, you're right, completely forgot about the 24h. What a sneaky clever tactic with waiting for the bounty to run out and having the CW in "sneak mode" :)

Answer (score 136, accepted):

#### Why the error occurs

In PHP, a regular expression needs to be enclosed within a pair of [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character; `/`, `#`, `~` are the most commonly used ones. Note that it is also possible to use bracket style delimiters where the opening and closing brackets are the starting and ending delimiter, i.e. `<pattern_goes_here>`, `[pattern_goes_here]` etc. are all valid.

The "*Unknown modifier X*" error usually occurs in the following two cases:

- > When your regular expression is **missing delimiters**.
- > When you use the **delimiter inside** the pattern **without escaping** it.

In this case, the regular expression is `<div[^>]*><ul[^>]*>`. The regex engine considers everything from `<` to `>` as the regex pattern, and everything afterwards as modifiers.

```
Regex: <div[^>  ]*><ul[^>]*>
       │     │  │          │
       └──┬──┘  └────┬─────┘
       pattern    modifiers
```

`]` here is an unknown modifier, because it appears after the closing `>` delimiter. Which is why PHP throws that error.

Depending on the pattern, the unknown modifier complaint might as well have been about `*`, `+`, `p`, `/` or `)` or almost any other letter/symbol. Only `imsxeADSUXJu` are [valid PCRE modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

#### How to fix it

The fix is easy. Just wrap your regex pattern with any valid delimiters. In this case, you could chose <kbd>**~**</kbd> and get the following:

```
~<div[^>]*><ul[^>]*>~
│                   │
│                   └─ ending delimiter
└───────────────────── starting delimiter
```

If you're receiving this error despite having used a delimiter, it might be because the pattern itself contains unescaped occurrences of the said delimiter.

#### Or escape delimiters

`/foo[^/]+bar/i` would certainly throw an error. So you can escape it using a <kbd>**\**</kbd> backslash if it appears anywhere within the regex:

```
/foo[^\/]+bar/i
│      │     │
└──────┼─────┴─ actual delimiters
       └─────── escaped slash(/) character
```

This is a tedious job if your regex pattern contains so many occurrences of the delimiter character.

The cleaner way, of course, would be to use a different delimiter altogether. Ideally a character that does not appear anywhere inside the regex pattern, say `#` - `#foo[^/]+bar#i`.

#### More reading:

- [PHP regex delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)
- http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html
- [How can I convert ereg expressions to preg in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6270004) (missing delimiters)
- [Unknown modifier '/' in …? what is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3565615) (on using [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php))

Comment: I noticed that the same occurs when one of the delimiters is inside a `preg_quote()`, thus something like `preg_replace('/'.preg_quote('/').'/i','',$string);` gives the same error of the topic. Shouldn't the slash get escaped by `preg_quote()`?

Comment: I ran into this when updating some old `ereg` calls to `preg_match`. Had to introduce delimiters.

Answer (score 20):

#### Other examples

The [reference answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20705419) already explains the reason for "Unknown modifier" warnings. This is just a comparison of other typical variants.

- When forgetting to add regex `/`delimiters`/`, the first non-letter symbol will be assumed to be one. Therefore the warning is often about what follows a grouping `(…)`, `[…]` meta symbol:

  ```
  preg_match("[a-zA-Z]+:\s*.$"
              ↑      ↑⬆
  ```
- Sometimes your regex already uses a custom delimiter (`:` here), but still contains the same character as unescaped literal. It's then mistaken as premature delimiter. Which is why the very next symbol receives the "Unknown modifier ❌" trophy:

  ```
  preg_match(":\[[\d:/]+\]:"
              ↑     ⬆     ↑
  ```
- When using the classic `/` delimiter, take care to not have it within the regex literally. This most frequently happens when trying to match [unescaped filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684220/preg-match-unknown-modifier-h-in-php):

  ```
  preg_match("/pathname/filename/i"
              ↑        ⬆         ↑
  ```

  Or when matching angle/square bracket style [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026387/why-preg-replace-throws-me-a-unknown-modifier-error):

  ```
  preg_match("/<%tmpl:id>(.*)</%tmpl:id>/Ui"
              ↑               ⬆         ↑
  ```
- Templating-style (Smarty or BBCode) regex patterns often require `{…}` or `[…]` brackets. Both should usually be escaped. (An outermost `{}` pair being the exception though).

  They also get misinterpreted as *paired delimiters* when no actual delimiter is used. If they're then also used as literal character within, then that's, of course … an error.

  ```
  preg_match("{bold[^}]+}"
              ↑      ⬆  ↑
  ```
- Whenever the warning says "**Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash**" then you also entirely forgot delimiters:

  ```
  preg_match("ab?c*"
              ↑
  ```
- "**Unkown modifier 'g'**" often indicates a regex that was copied verbatimly from JavaScript or Perl.

  ```
  preg_match("/abc+/g"
                    ⬆
  ```

  PHP doesn't use the `/g` global flag. Instead the [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) function works on all occurences, and [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) is the "global" searching pendant to the one-occurence [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match).

  So, just remove the `/g` flag.

  See also:
  · [Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'g'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19061037/warning-preg-replace-unknown-modifier-g)
  · [preg_replace: bad regex == 'Unknown Modifier'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653055/preg-replace-bad-regex-unknown-modifier)
- A more peculiar case pertains the **PCRE_EXTENDED `/x` flag**. This is often (or should be) used for making regexps more lofty and readable.

  This allows to use inline `#` comments. PHP implements the regex delimiters atop PCRE. But it doesn't treat `#` in any special way. Which is how a literal delimiter in a `#` comment can become an error:

  ```
  preg_match("/
     ab?c+  # Comment with / slash in between
  /x"
  ```

  (Also noteworthy that using `#` as `#abc+#x` delimiter can be doubly inadvisable.)
- Interpolating variables into a regex requires them to be pre-escaped, or be valid regexps themselves. You can't tell beforehand if this is gonna work:

  ```
   preg_match("/id=$var;/"
               ↑    ↺   ↑
  ```

  It's best to apply [`$var = preg_quote($var, "/")`](http://php.net/preg_quote) in such cases.

  See also:
  · [Unknown modifier '/' in ...? what is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565615/unknown-modifier-in-what-is-it)

  Another alternative is using `\Q…\E` escapes for unquoted literal strings:

  ```
   preg_match("/id=\Q{$var}\E;/mix");
  ```

  Note that this is merely a convenience shortcut for meta symbols, not dependable/safe. It would fall apart in case that `$var` contained a literal `'\E'` itself (however unlikely). And it does [**not** mask the delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41526755/literal-delimiter-delimiter-inside-q-e-block) itself.
- **Deprecated modifier /e** is an entirely different problem. This has nothing to do with delimiters, but the implicit expression interpretation mode being phased out. See also:  [Replace deprecated preg_replace /e with preg_replace_callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19245205/replace-deprecated-preg-replace-e-with-preg-replace-callback)

#### Alternative regex delimiters

As mentioned already, the quickest solution to this error is just picking a distinct delimiter. Any non-letter symbol can be used. Visually distinctive ones are often preferred:

- `~abc+~`
- `!abc+!`
- `@abc+@`
- `#abc+#`
- `=abc+=`
- `%abc+%`

Technically you could use `$abc$` or `|abc|` for delimiters. However, it's best to avoid symbols that serve as regex meta characters themselves.

The hash `#` as delimiter is rather popular too. But care should be taken in combination with the `x`/`PCRE_EXTENDED` readability modifier. You can't use `# inline` or `(?#…)` comments then, because those would be confused as delimiters.

#### Quote-only delimiters

Occassionally you see `"` and `'` used as regex delimiters paired with their conterpart as PHP string enclosure:

```
  preg_match("'abc+'"
  preg_match('"abc+"'
```

Which is perfectly valid as far as PHP is concerned. It's sometimes convenient and unobtrusive, but not always legible in IDEs and editors.

#### Paired delimiters

An interesting variation are paired delimiters. Instead of using the same symbol on both ends of a regex, you can use any `<...>` `(...)` `[...]` `{...}` bracket/braces combination.

```
  preg_match("(abc+)"   # just delimiters here, not a capture group
```

While most of them also serve as regex meta characters, you can often use them without further effort. As long as those specific braces/parens within the regex are paired or escaped correctly, these variants are quite readable.

#### Fancy regex delimiters

A somewhat lazy trick (which is not endorsed hereby) is using non-printable ASCII characters as delimiters. This works easily in PHP by using double quotes for the regex string, and octal escapes for delimiters:

```
 preg_match("\001 abc+ \001mix"
```

The `\001` is just a control character <kbd>␁</kbd> that's not usually needed. Therefore it's highly unlikely to appear within most regex patterns. Which makes it suitable here, even though not very legible.

Sadly you can't use Unicode glyps `❚` as delimiters. PHP only allows single-byte characters. And why is that? Well, glad you asked:

#### PHPs delimiters atop PCRE

The [`preg_*`](http://php.net/preg) functions utilize the [PCRE](http://www.google.com/search?q=PCRE) regex engine, which itself doesn't care or provide for delimiters. For resemblence with Perl the `preg_*` functions implement them. Which is also why you can use [modifier letters `/ism`](http://php.net/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers) instead of just [constants as parameter](http://php.net/pcre.constants).

See [ext/pcre/php_pcre.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c#L310) on how the regex string is preprocessed:

- First all leading whitespace is ignored.
- Any non-alphanumeric symbol is taken as presumed delimiter. Note that PHP only honors single-byte characters:

  ```
  delimiter = *p++;
  if (isalnum((int)*(unsigned char *)&delimiter) || delimiter == '\\') {
          php_error_docref(NULL,E_WARNING, "Delimiter must not…");
          return NULL;
  }
  ```
- The rest of the regex string is traversed left-to-right. Only backslash `\\`-escaped symbols are ignored. [`\Q` and `\E` escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518758/how-the-preg-match-handles-the-delimiter-when-q-e-used) is not honored.
- Should the delimiter be found again, the remainder is verified to only contain modifier letters.
- If the delimiter is one of the `([{< )]}> )]}>` pairable braces/brackets, then the processing logic is more elaborate.

  ```
  int brackets = 1;   /* brackets nesting level */
  while (*pp != 0) {
          if (*pp == '\\' && pp[1] != 0) pp++;
          else if (*pp == end_delimiter && --brackets <= 0)
                  break;
          else if (*pp == start_delimiter)
                  brackets++;
          pp++;
  }
  ```

  It looks for correctly paired left and right delimiter, but ignores other braces/bracket types when counting.
- The raw regex string is passed to the PCRE backend only after delimiter and modifier flags have been cut out.

Now this is all somewhat irrelevant. But explains where the delimiter warnings come from. And this whole procedure is all to have a minimum of Perl compatibility. There are a few minor deviations of course, like the `[…]` character class context not receiving special treatment in PHP.

#### More references

- [preg_match(); - Unknown modifier '+'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589807/preg-match-unknown-modifier)
- [Unknown modifier '/' error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719915/unknown-modifier-error-in-php)
- [PHP RegExpr error Unkown modifier '('](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888496/php-regexpr-error-unkown-modifier/)
- [Unknown modifier '(' when using preg_match() with a REGEX expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153261/unknown-modifier-when-using-preg-match-with-a-regex-expression)
- [PHP: Regex - Unknown modifier error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862238/php-regex-unknown-modifier-error)
- [Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '('](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941273/warning-preg-match-function-preg-match-unknown-modifier)
- [When does preg_match(): Unknown modifier error occur?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794101/when-does-preg-match-unknown-modifier-error-occur)
  <sup>(Just a well-written question demonstrating prior research)</sup>

Comment: Very nice explanation

Comment: Super helpful! Thanks. I was really struggling to wrap my head around some of the why's and wherefores behind the syntax...

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to get an exception (`MalformedPatternException`), instead of warnings or using `preg_last_error()` - consider using [T-Regx library](https://t-regx.com):

```
<?php
try 
{
    return pattern('invalid] pattern')->match($s)->all();
}
catch (MalformedPatternException $e) 
{
    // your pattern was invalid
}
```