# Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier ']'

Tags: preg-replace, preg-match

I am getting the error in this code:

```
$pattern="{[^}]*}";

$this->output = preg_replace($pattern, "", $this->output);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '\]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705399/warning-preg-replace-unknown-modifier)* (same reason, missing regular expression delimiters)

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the curly bracket:

```
$pattern="{[^\}]*}";
```

If your delimiters are `{` and `}`.

But I think you miss the regular expression delimiter:

```
$pattern="/\{[^\}]*\}/";
```