# preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'h' in php

Tags: php

This error is shown when trying to match an array of words to a user typed text..

```
     foreach($items as $k=>$item){
        if($item!='' && preg_match("/".$item."/", $opText)){
          if(!in_array($item,$params[$val['name']],true)){
             $params[$val['name']][]=$item;
          }
        }
     }
```

Comment: most probably `$item` contains a `/` followed by a `h`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$item` has a `/` in it, which means that it thinks that the regex ends sooner than it does.

```
/goldfish/herring/
//        ^ Not actually a modifier (h) - just an unescaped string
```

You can use the [`preg_quote($string, '/')`](http://www.php.net/preg_quote) function for this to turn it into the following:

```
/goldfish\/herring/
//       ^ Escaped
```

**Usage**:

```
 foreach($items as $k=>$item){
    if($item!='' && preg_match("/".preg_quote($item,"/")."/", $opText)){
      if(!in_array($item,$params[$val['name']],true)){
         $params[$val['name']][]=$item;
      }
    }
 }
```

**Tip**:

If this is a hardcoded regex, you can change your escape character to make the regex easier to read by not having to escape a commonly used character:

```
~goldfish/herring~
//       ^       ^
//       |       \- Using a different modifier
//       |       
//       \- Different from the modifier, so we don't have to escape it
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have dynamic input, it would be wise to use [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/preg_quote) to be sure that this input doesn't violate any regular expression rules.

```
foreach($items as $k=>$item){
   if($item!='' && preg_match("/".preg_quote($item, '/')."/", $opText)){
     if(!in_array($item,$params[$val['name']],true)){
         $params[$val['name']][]=$item;
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [preg_quote()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php):

```
preg_match("/".preg_quote($item)."/", $opText)
```