# Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'h'

Tags: preg-replace, modifier

I've created a site using concrete5 5.6.3.2.  I've used the code in this thread to try and help my thumb nail cached images have a more seo friendly look, line 36 highlighted.

https://www.concrete5.org/index.php?cID=540812&editmode=

After I put the file into my root helpers folder, on one of my blog posts thumbnail images, I see this error instead of the thumbnail:

Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'h' in /home/foundry/public_html/helpers/image.php on line 36

I've since created a new blog and the thumbnail does not have the same issue.

This is what my root/helpers/image.php code looks like, line 36 in bold:

```
defined('C5_EXECUTE') or die("Access Denied.");
```

class ImageHelper extends Concrete5_Helper_Image {public function getThumbnail($obj, $maxWidth, $maxHeight, $crop = false) {
      $fID = false;
      if ($obj instanceof File) {
         $path = $obj->getPath();
         $fID = $obj->getFileID();
      } else {
         $path = $obj;
      }

```
  /* BEGIN: Updated code */

  $fh = Loader::helper('file');
  $suffix = $this->jpegCompression; // Add prefix for compression level to serve the properly compressed images
  $suffix .= ($crop ? '-1' : '-0'); // Name cropped images different from resized images so they don't get mixed up in the cache

  **$origName = strtolower(preg_replace('/_/', '-', preg_replace('/.'.$fh->getExtension($path).'$/', '', substr(strrchr($path, "/"), 1))));**

  if (file_exists($path) && $fID) {
     $filename = $origName . '-' . $maxWidth . '-' . $maxHeight . '-' . $suffix . '-' . $fID . '.' . $fh->getExtension($path);
  } else if (file_exists($path)) {
     $filename = $origName . '-' . $maxWidth . '-' . $maxHeight . '-' . $suffix . '-0.' . $fh->getExtension($path); 
  } else if ($fID) {
     $filename = $origName . '-' . $maxWidth . '-' . $maxHeight . '-' . $suffix . '-' . $fID . $fh->getExtension($path);
  } else {
     $filename = $origName . '-' . $maxWidth . '-' . $maxHeight . '-' . $suffix . '-0.' . $fh->getExtension($path);         
  }

  /* END: Updated code */

  if (!file_exists(DIR_FILES_CACHE . '/' . $filename)) {
     // create image there
     $this->create($path, DIR_FILES_CACHE . '/' . $filename, $maxWidth, $maxHeight, $crop);
  }

  $src = REL_DIR_FILES_CACHE . '/' . $filename;
  $abspath = DIR_FILES_CACHE . '/' . $filename;
  $thumb = new stdClass;
  if (isset($abspath) && file_exists($abspath)) {         
     $thumb->src = $src;
     $dimensions = getimagesize($abspath);
     $thumb->width = $dimensions[0];
     $thumb->height = $dimensions[1];
     return $thumb;
  }
```

}}

The site page link is http://www.pentictonfoundry.com/news/

Thanks to anyone for feedback on this, I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: preg\_replace(): Unknown modifier '\]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705399/warning-preg-replace-unknown-modifier)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that paths have a slash in them. Use a different delimiter such as : to do your replace.

Comment: Thanks Barett.  I wasn't sure so reposted the blog post and it didn't replicate itself.  If it happens again, I will apply your fix.  Thanks again, I super appreciate it.