# Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '&lt;'

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to run a regex which I debugged on online php regex test website.

This is the full regex:

```
$rule = '/[\s\S]*<(b|strong)>[\s\S]*notes:[\s\S]*<(\/b|\/strong)>([\s\S]*?)<(b|strong)>(sources|source|citation|data sources|last update)[\s\S]*/im';
```

Even with a simpler test regex:

```
$rule = "/[\s\S]*<(b|strong)>[\s\S]*/im";
```

I still get an error from this code:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match($source_html, $rule, $matches);
```

The error I receive is:

**Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '&lt;' in .../FragmentGrabber.php on line 63**

I'm at my wits end trying to resolve this issue on my local box. Is there anyway to resolve this warning and have my regex work without error. I've tried fixing the escape characters of my regex but that's not helping. Perhaps there is a character encoding issue?! Please note the literal `&lt;` in the output vs `<`.

**Edit:**

Here is a snippet of my class, I'll post the whole thing if someone really wants.

```
  // d() below is the Kint debugger.
  public function get_fragments_by_name($source_html, $name)
  {
    $matches = array();
    $rule = self::generate_regex_rule($name);
    preg_match($source_html, $rule, $matches);
    return $matches;
  }

  private function generate_regex_rule($name)
  {
    $end_tags = self::get_end_tag_options($name);
    $rule = "/[\s\S]*<(b|strong)>[\s\S]*/";# . $name . ":[\s\S]*<(\/b|\/strong)>([\s\S]*?)<(b|strong)>(" . $end_tags . ")[\s\S]*/im";
    d($rule);
    return $rule;
  }
```

Comment: This apparently is not the real source code resulting in that crash. From the error message one can see that something converts your `<` to `&lt;`, so the html special char replacement. That does not happen by accident or implicit. Please show your _real_ code.

Comment: ok, please see my edit. I can show you the whole code if you want in a Gist or something but its 126 LOC and I dont like pasting walls of code usually.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20705399/3933332

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) arguments are in the wrong order. First should be the regular expression.

So change:

```
preg_match($source_html, $rule, $matches);
```

to:

```
preg_match($rule, $source_html, $matches);
```

Comment: Thanks! Good eye! ... I wish IDEs could catch this.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try passing $rule as the first argument:

```
preg_match($rule, $source_html, $matches);
```

Please refer to PHP manual for the details: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 1):

The parameters must be used like this (from PHP documentation):

> int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )

so you need to do:

```
preg_match($rule, $source_html, $matches);
```