# regex unknown modifier

Tags: php

I keep getting this error when using preg_replace that's mixed with some html.

Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'd'

here is the code I used.

it's removing that bit of html from the beginning of a string that contains html.

```
$foo = preg_replace("/^<div id='IDHERE'>sometext.</div>/", '', $foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `/` because it is used to end the first part of the regex string, after which a modifier such as `g` (global) is used and `d` is not a valid option there (the d from div).

Make it `\/`

```
            $foo = preg_replace("/^<div id='IDHERE'>sometext.<\/div>/", '', $foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape the closing `</div>` tag:

```
$foo = preg_replace("/^<div id='IDHERE'>sometext.<\/div>/", '', $foo);
```

PHP was interpreting the forward slash in the closing div tag as being the end of the expression:

```
/^<div id='IDHERE'>sometext.</div>/
                             ^ PHP thinks this is the end,
                               then complains about the unknown modifier 'd'
```

Answer (score 0):

add `\` in your pattern:

```
 $foo = preg_replace("/^<div id='IDHERE'>sometext.<\/div>/", '', $foo);
```

and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705399/warning-preg-replace-unknown-modifier) reference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `/` in `</div>`, so your regex should be:

```
$foo = preg_replace("/^<div id='IDHERE'>sometext.<\/div>/", '', $foo);
```

Comment: Also, this is a good resource for testing: http://www.phpliveregex.com/