# Wordpress WYSIWYG adding &nbsp; to html

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress site and the WYSIWYG is used to create posts with external page links in the content.
The links are working but not opening in a new tab, despite selecting the option to open in new tab.

When I check the source code in the admin area it is correct with `target="_blank"` attribute. However when the post is published and I inspect the element on the page it adds `&nbsp;` in various places, one of these places is before the target="_blank" so it becomes `&nbsp;target` all one word and therefore means target doesn't work.

I don't have much knowledge of PHP, but have tried some similar suggested fixes without any luck.

This is one solution I have tried that did not work:

```
<?php echo preg_replace('~\s?<p>(\s|&nbsp;)+</p>\s?~', '', get_field('client_gallery')); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = preg_replace('<p>(\s|&nbsp;)*+(<br\s*/*>)?(\s|&nbsp;)*</p>', '', $content);
```

try this code which will remove both empty paragraph and break tag.

Comment: Hi Ragu, Thanks for your reply. I tried this fix and got an error on the page:
Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 
Sorry I do not have much php knowledge.

Comment: try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705399/warning-preg-replace-unknown-modifier)