# Why does the delimiter used affect the validity of a regex?

Tags: php, regex

I use this pretty simple regular expression:

```
^[\x20-\x7E]+$
```

When I try to use it with some of PHP regex functions, such as [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) it throws warning in sole case when I use `~` character (tilde) as delimiter.

So, execution of following lines goes well

```
preg_match("/^[\x20-\x7E]+$/", $s); # delimiter "/"
preg_match("!^[\x20-\x7E]+$!", $s); # delimiter "!"
preg_match("#^[\x20-\x7E]+$#", $s); # delimiter "#"
```

but for some reason, this line

```
preg_match("~^[\x20-\x7E]+$~", $s); # delimiter "~"
```

throws a warning

```
Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier ']' in some_script.php on line XX
```

note: it happens only when it's used with double-quotes!

I'm using tilde all the time as delimiter and never faced problems with it until this case and really wonder why that happens. Can't find does tilde have some special meaning in regular expressions (i'm 99% now sure it does not), or it's just a bug.

I can certainly work around this, but the question is: **What's the difference between tilde and any other delimiter?**

Comment: Just use something else then!

Comment: @GordonM Question is not how to solve this, it's WHY IT HAPPENS? ;)

Comment: Hmm, does it think that `$~` is a variable? try single quotes... `'~^[\x20-\x7E]+$~'`

Comment: @rock321987 maybe it's PHP 5.4.16 problem and this line actually stands in code as `if (preg_match("~^[\x20-\x7E]+$~", $s) === 1) {...}` where `$s` is any string.

Comment: in php 5.5 the same - https://eval.in/595641

Comment: @BitwiseCreative It works with single quotes, forgot to mention that, and good point, never thought about variable problem. Maybe it sees that as variable but I think that it should throw another warning like `Undefined variable: ~ in ...` like it does with "$x" when $x is not set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were using double quotes:

```
 "~^[\x20-\x7E]+$~"
```

Which means that both `\x20` and `\x7E` got interpreted in PHP string context, not by PCRE. Guess what [`\x7E`](http://ascii.cl/) amounts to.

So as @Bitwise mentioned, use single quotes. Or better yet escape the escape sequences:

```
 "~^[\\x20-\\x7E]+$~"
```

Thus the regex engine will still see `[\x20-\x7E]` instead of `[ -~]`.

Comment: nice, escaping-escapes really helps... but still holds this question, what's the difference between "~" and "#" or "!" as delimiters from PCRE's point of view... with other delimiters I don't have to escape escapes and expression is still between double quotes ;)

Comment: There's no difference. Your tilde regex was failing because PCRE saw `[ -~]` (an unescaped delimiter).

Comment: PCRE doesn't really know about PHPs delimiters. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31231183/345031

Comment: @mario Aw, I see now that 7E is actually a tilde character! Have not realized that at first. Problem solved!

Comment: `Or better yet` using double quotes without needing to, and then escaping unwanted interpolation is not "better".

Comment: @AD7six Perhaps. Understanding string contexts is more worthwhile than a generalized workaround. As is often forgotten, the backslash also escapes itself in single quotes.

Comment: Understanding is important, and useful; using a language feature you don't want (double quotes), and then dealing with the side effects is not imo better. The simple rule "always use single quoted strings [unless you have to use double quotes]" avoids these surprises/problems at no cost - especially the cost of readability.

Comment: @AD7six I'll admit that's just me being pompous and "look at clever me". Albeit I'd really escape it `'~^[\\x20-\\x7E]+$~'` in single quotes still. (AKA: this post was brought to you by the OCD department). So I only opt for single quotes on lengthier regexps, and edge cases where escaping became too tedious/unreadable.