# Make sure only numbers and periods are entered in php $_GET

Tags: php, regex

Sounds simple, but I can't seem to find the right regex formula to only allow numbers and periods in a string.

This is what I found, but gives me an error:

```
    if (!empty($get_version) && preg_match('^[0-9.]*$', $get_version)) {
      // Do something
    }
    else {
      // Get default value
    }
```

Comment: `'/^[0-9.]*$/'`

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated.

Comment: When they mark questions as duplicates, why the heck don't they link it to that "duplicate" question then?? So frustrating.

Comment: It is to the right of the big zero on the left. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705399/warning-preg-replace-unknown-modifier