# Literal delimiter ( delimiter inside \Q \E block )

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I've been trying to make a few of functions based on `RegEx` and most of them use `\Q` and `\E` as some of the `RegEx` `pattern` is user input.

So, let's say hypothetically that we're using the `delimiter` `/` and want to match it against `/` the function would construct something amongst the lines of `/\Q/\E/`.

I'm not sure why `/\Q/\E/` doesn't match `/` but with every other delimiter it does, unless you use the same delimiter as `input`.

Maybe, it considers the delimiter the end, even though, it's in a literal-only block and the escape as literal. Not sure, tried a bunch.

Hopefully someone can push me into the right direction as to what workarounds there are for this issue.

Comment: Is there anything keeping you from using another delimiter or just escape the `/`, without using `\Q` and `\E`

Comment: @SebastianProske Using a different delimiter will move the issue and not solve it, the user input could also be whatever other delimiter I might use. Also, not using `\Q` and `\E` is a security issue in this case. TL:DR - Yes, a few things in fact.

Comment: @SebastianProske Err, that was dense. I thought preg_quote only backslashed the quote. Sorry & Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to understand that `/` is not a regex metacharacter, like `*` or `(`.  It's special because you're using it to delimit the regex itself, and the only way to escape the regex delimiter is with a backslash (`\/`).

But you shouldn't need to use `\Q` and `\E`.  The [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) method takes a `delimiter` argument, so it correctly adds backslashes everywhere they're needed.

Comment: I'm aware of that. However, I really do need to use `\Q` and `\E` since I don't want `regex` characters to be interpreted as such. All the input should be literal.

Comment: @Removed So how do you handle a `\E` inserted by the user? Have you read what `preg_quote` does?

Comment: @SebastianProske Updated post with an illustration as to `why`

Comment: @SebastianProske Yes, I'm fully aware of what `preg_quote` does as I stated already preciously. It wouldn't work in this case because you'd get:  `/\Q\/\E/` which doesn't match `/`.

Comment: @Removed get rid of `\Q` and `\E` and just use `preg_quote`, as stated in this answer.

Comment: @SebastianProske Yes, and then, as in my illustration, entire `$start` and `$end` will be interpreted as RegEx, ruining the entire point of writing a function like that. Trust me, this answer is not even close to good.

Comment: @SebastianProske A better answer is to go with my current ghetto fix which is to ban the delimiter from user input entirely so I can still use `\Q` and `\E` for the rest, but this seems unnecessarily ugly.

Comment: @SebastianProske Do you even know what `\Q` and `\E` is?

Comment: Yep, I'm just too dump to understand your problem. http://ideone.com/AfsI0O