# How to match all "types" and escape the regex properly?

Tags: php, regex

I am currently struggling to match the content of following "Types":

```
(Type): multiplechoice
(Category): 0
(Random answers): 0
(Question): Which of the following is true about pre-test imagery?

(Type): multiplechoice
(Category): 0
(Random answers): 1
(Question): Which of the following is not true about the TMJ?
```

I am trying:

```
preg_match_all("(Type)\:(.+?)\n", $content, $types);
```

But I get an unknown modifier "\" as an error message.

How can I properly match all the types? Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: preg\_replace(): Unknown modifier '\]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705399/warning-preg-replace-unknown-modifier)

Comment: You need to use delimiters in PHP with regexs. http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php You also need to escape special regex characters `()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do, assuming there is space after :

```
preg_match_all('/\((.+?)\): (.*)?/i', $subject, $array, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Comment: This doesn't find `Type`s only. You also should explain what you did (the `i` modifier has no use because there are no alpha characters).

Comment: i is for case insensitive to match the keyword, it finds type and content in binary array

Comment: `A`or `a` will be matched by `.` regardless of `i`.

Comment: True , This was done by habit of keeping things case insensitive. you can remove it if you like.