# Are \Q and \E supposed to escape the delimiter in PCRE?

Tags: php, regex, perl, pcre

I am generating regex automatically to validate URLs. To avoid clashes I am simply escaping regular text with `\Q` and `\E`. Unfortunately I discovered that this syntax does not work as it should in PHP:

```
reg_match('/\Qfoo/bar\E/', 'foo/bar')
PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'b' in ... code on line ...
```

But it works in `grep`:

```
$ echo 'foo/bar' | grep -P '\Qfoo/bar\E'
foo/bar
```

And in regex101:

https://regex101.com/r/mKI0Q9/1

But not in Perl:

```
$ echo 'foo/bar' | perl -ne 'print $_ if m/\Qfoo/bar\E/'
Backslash found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "m/\Qfoo/bar\"
```

Does `\Q` and `\E` are supposed to escape the delimiter?

Comment: In PHP the delimiters are handled somewhat crudely [beforehand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705399/warning-preg-replace-unknown-modifier), not by the PCRE library which knows about \Q and \E.

Comment: What would be wrong with just using `[foo/bar]`?  By the way, I don't see much point of surrounding that text with `\Q ... \E` anyway, because it contains no actual regex meta characters.

Comment: `/` has no special meaning to `grep`, since it doesn't use delimiters.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Square brackets aren't used for grouping in regexp.

Comment: Why don't you use `preg_quote()`?

Comment: In your source code, `\Q` and `\E` do not handle the RE delimiter.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Because I am not matching `foo/bar` but anything that could be a regex such as `/\r\n.*?(?\$)`

Comment: @Barmar Yes `preg_quote()` looks like a good candidate to my particular case, but it does not answer the question title.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That doesn't seem to be a good dup, it doesn't discuss `\Q...\E` in source code.

Comment: The documentation says that it ignores metacharacters in the pattern. The delimiters aren't in the pattern, they're used to find the pattern in the first place.

Comment: @Barmar: It does now (more explicitly). // As for Perl, I believe that's more of a language tokenizer issue (never looked into that though).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew There are also lots of questions that say that `.` must be escaped if you want it treated literally. That can be escaped with `\Q` and `\E`. The delimiter is different, it can't be escaped this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) is not explicit about this. What it says is:

> `\Q` and `\E` can be used to ignore regexp metacharacters in the pattern. For example: `\w+\Q.$.\E$` will match one or more word characters, followed by literals `.$.` and anchored at the end of the string.

However, the delimiters aren't "metacharacters in the pattern". They're used to determine where the pattern ends. So the order of operations apparently is:

1. Find the pattern in the input string, looking for matching delimiters.
2. Escape any special characters between `\Q` and `\E` within the pattern.
3. Do the rest of regexp parsing.

[Perl documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Gory-details-of-parsing-quoted-constructs) is clearer, describing parsing of quoted constructs in general (regular expressions are just one particular form of this).

> The first pass is finding the end of the quoted construct....
>   When searching for single-character delimiters, escaped delimiters and \ are skipped....
>   During this search no attention is paid to the semantics of the construct.

and elsewhere:

> For the pattern of regex operators (`qr//`, `m//` and `s///`), the quoting from `\Q` is applied after interpolation is processed, but before escapes are processed.

But this is still after it has first found the end of the regexp.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the answer to incorporate some bits of that.